# Use Laravel together with Lumen

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm currently making a game where the main website is using the Laravel framework. It uses Angular as the front-end. I want to connect to the game (to do some CRUD actions) with Lumen, so Angular should use Lumen as an API.

I want to host the Lumen API as a subfolder of Laravel (for example in http://www.example.com/data). How can I do this? I only see guides to put the API in a complete new website or subdomain.

Comment: Um, Lumen is just Laravel with parts turned off...you can't run Laravel what is essentially twice in the same project. Since you are already running Laravel you would just make a route group 'data' to handle your API. The only way is fire up another project in the same server with lumen as the base

Comment: It sounds as if you're mixing WAY too many things. As @RobFonseca said, Lumen is just a stripped-down Laravel. If you're using Angular as a front-end that queries Lumen as a back-end API, why do you need Laravel in the first place? Just set up your API on its own Subdomain (ie: http://api.example.com) and use Angular as a front-end on the primary domain (http://example.com) without having to worry about conflicts with Blade. Otherwise, you can keep all of your API calls in Laravel and devote a controller to your /data route to serve up your API's JSON responses.

Comment: I don't think this is mixing up way too many things. Not all views might be rendered by the JS client (we use Vue), the initial view being one of them. Further, you may want to have CLI Commands for maintenance tasks or the like. Laravel can handle all these things well, but Lumen doesn't provide them. Then there is the API. Laravel can do this as well, yet there is a big performance cost due to bootstrapping and middleware that cannot be set per route. This is were one wants to add Lumen. However, I think it should just be a separate service and project that may talk to the same DB.